# Gradle task groovyDoc failing with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, gradle, groovydoc

I'm using Gradle 1.5 to test my Groovy scripts. The groovyDoc task in build.gradle is set up like:

```
groovydoc {
    docTitle = "Name"
    windowTitle = "Name"
    destinationDir = file('file://path')
}
```

The error I'm getting when running this task is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':groovydoc'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fusesource/jansi/AnsiRenderWriter
```

This only started happening after I made a minor code change (adding a single If statement) to one of my classes. I reverted to the previous commit and it does not have this problem. I tried deleting my change in the class and recommitting the same file but it is still failing.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I upgraded to the current version of Gradle (1.10) and continued to get the same error.

Added the following to my build.gradle and now it's working.

```
configurations {
    jansi.extendsFrom(runtime)
}
groovydoc {
    def title = "IPDS ${version}"
    groovyClasspath = project.configurations.jansi
}
dependencies {
    jansi 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11'
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. Having run Gradle 1.10 since its release, this error just started happening - this fix does take care of it, but it's still odd.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupt Gradle installation that's missing the Jansi Jar. Try to run with `--full-stacktrace` to learn more about the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Peter. I checked my Gradle installation and I have the jansi-1.2.1.jar in that directory. My groovyDoc task works if I checkout the last successful commit. I ran the --full-stacktrace flag but it doesn't mean much to me. It's here if you want to look at it: http://pastebin.com/1infzqtY

Comment: So it's Groovy(Doc) that attempts to use Jansi but for some reason doesn't see it. I recommend to try with the latest Gradle version. If the problem persists, please file an issue at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Worth noting that this is on the Gradle forum: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_task_groovydoc_failing_with_noclassdeffounderror